# open and close an application using subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

I want a .py program to open and close an application.  I tried to open safari with:

```
import time
import subprocess
p = subprocess.run(['open', '-a', 'safari'])
time.sleep(3)
p.terminate()
```

The open works, but the close does not.
I also tried: `p = subprocess.Popen(['open', '-a', 'safari'])` instead of `.run`
What am I doing wrong?  I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but I'm using Atom editor with the Terminus package.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `open` actually maintains a handle to the application. Try running and terminating a different process

Comment: Another problem is that `run` will actually wait for the command to complete: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html . You will have to use Popen constructor .